# Proving Theorem 1.16, Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am confused about the proof of Theorem 1.16 in Folland's Real Analysis, in particular the two statements underlined below:

[image]

1. In the part underlined in red, the book uses both continuity from above and from below, but in my proof I only used continuity from above. I probably make mistakes and please point it out:

> My attempt: 
> Since $\mu$ is continuous from above, denote $E_n := (x, x+\frac{1}{n}]$ and $\mu(E_1) < \infty$, 
> then we have $\mu(\bigcap_1^{\infty} E_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n)$, i.e., $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 $ s.t. $\mu((x, x+\delta]) < \epsilon$. 
> Therefore, when $x \geq 0$: 
> $$\mu((0, x+\delta]) - \mu((0, x]) = F(x+\delta) - F(x) < \epsilon$$
> When $x<0$:
> $$\mu((x, 0]) - \mu((x+\delta, 0]) = F(x+\delta) - F(x) < \epsilon$$
> So $\mu$ is right-continuous.

2. In the part underlined in blue, the book says it's evident on $\mathcal{A}$, but I don't understand why it's only on $\mathcal{A}$ (why not evident on $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$):

> My attempt: 
> $a=b$:
> $$\mu((a,b]) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0 = \mu_F((a,a]) = F(a) - F(a)$$
> $a<b\leq 0$:
> $$\mu((a,b]) = \mu((a,0]) - \mu((b,0]) = F(b) - F(a) = \mu_F((a,b])$$
> $0\leq a<b$:
> $$\mu((a,b]) = \mu((0,b]) - \mu((0,a]) = F(b) - F(a) = \mu_F((a,b])$$
> $a \leq 0 <b$:
> $$\mu((a,b]) = \mu((a,0]) + \mu((0,b]) = F(b) - F(a) = \mu_F((a,b])$$

The above are probably my misunderstanding and please feel free to corret me. Thanks!

Comment: 1. You use continuity from below when you prove right-continuity at $x<0$.

Comment: $\mathcal{R}=\{(a,b]: -\infty<a\leq b<\infty\}$ is a $\pi$ system and the measures $\mu_F$ and $\mu$ are $\sigma$-finite. Apply Dynkin's theorem (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{R}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with $2$.

It's not *immediately* evident on $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb R}$ because general descriptions of Borel sets are hard to come by. Certainly not every Borel set looks like $(a,b]$, so your attempt doesn't address the case of $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb R}$- you haven't defined $\mathcal{A}$, but it seems to me that you have only shown it is evident that $\mu$ agrees with $\mu_F$ on $\mathcal{A}$... which the book already said.

For $1$: the tl;dr is that there's nothing wrong. Continuity of measure from below implies continuity of measure from above, so, it's not surprising you can prove right continuity using "only" the continuity from above.

You're correct in deducing that for any $x\in\Bbb R$, any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ with $\mu((x,x+h])<\epsilon$ for all $0\le h\le\delta$. Though, you didn't actually say that - to check right continuity of $F$, strictly speaking you should check the smallness condition for all $0\le h\le\delta$ rather than just for $h=\delta$ (but that's easy to fix).

When $x\ge0$, I like your proof. $\mu((0,x+h])-\mu((0,x])=\mu((x,x+h])$ and the result follows. For $x<0$: $$F(x+h)-F(x)=\mu((x,0])-\mu((x+h,0])=\mu((x,x+h])$$Is also correct if you take care to say, for $0<h<-x$. You can use the same continuity of intersections to prove the right continuity.

But this isn't surprising. After all, we prove the continuity of measure "from above" as a corollary of the continuity of measure "from below". I suspect what the authors hand in mind was a proof like this:

> Let $x\ge0$. Then because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu((0,x_n])=\mu((0,x])$, if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence with limit $x$, by the "continuity of $\mu$ from above", we find $F$ to be right continuous at $x$.
>
> Let $x<0$. Then because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu((x_n,0])=\mu((x,0])$, if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence with limit $x$, **by the continuity of $\mu$ from below**, we find $F$ to be right continuous at $x$.

Note: $$(x,0]=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}(x_n,0]$$In that case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction explanation! For 2., is it correct to prove it by:  

> First part of Theorem 1.16 shows  
>> If $F: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ is any increasing, right-continuous function, there is a unique Borel measure $\mu_F$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu_F=F(b) - F(a)$ for any $a,b$.  
>   
>Now since we proved $F$ is increasing and right-continuous and the Borel measure $\mu$ agrees with $\mu_F$ for any $a,b$, then $\mu=\mu_F$.  

Thanks!

Comment: @joy2020 That's a restatement of what Folland already said. "... there is a *unique* Borel measure ..." is the crux of the matter. So yes, it's correct.